# MS Access SQL join only display extra records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to display left over records after matching one-to-one rows. How do I display extra/left over records after joining two tables?

Suppose I have two tables, A and B. They both display the the same transactions at the end of the day.  However, Table A has more detail about the records but is late in getting updated. Table B, on the other hand, has limited information about transactions but is updated several hours before Table A.

I need a query that can return which records have yet to appear in Table A from Table B.

```
TABLE A
+-------+-----+---------+----------+---------------------------+
| NAME  |  ID | AMOUNT  |   TYPE   |    PROCESSED TIMESTAMP    |
+-------+-----+---------+----------+---------------------------+
|  ABC  | 123 | -420.07 | PURCHASE | 2018-09-06-08.26.32.000000|
|  ABC  | 123 |  420.07 | REFUND   | 2018-09-06-07.12.18.000000|
|  BBC  | 456 |   -5.00 | PURCHASE | 2018-09-06-10.25.13.000000|
+-------+-----+---------+----------+---------------------------+

TABLE B
+----+----------+---------------------------+
| ID |  AMOUNT  |    RECEIVED TIMESTAMP     |
+----+----------+---------------------------+
|123 |  -420.07 | 2018-09-05-09.26.15.000000|
|123 |   420.07 | 2018-09-05-08.12.03.000000|
|123 |  -420.07 | 2018-09-05-08.40.00.000000|
|456 |    -5.00 | 2018-09-05-08.45.00.000000|
+----+----------+---------------------------+

QUERY RESULTS
+----+----------+
| ID |  AMOUNT  |
+----+----------+
|123 |  -420.07 |
+----+----------+
```

I can manage to find all the records related to the ID that is "off balance" but I need only the specific records that are extra:

```
SELECT * FROM b
WHERE id 
IN
(SELECT d.id AS id 
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT id, ROUND(SUM(amount),2) AS balance FROM a GROUP BY id) c
    RIGHT JOIN
        (SELECT id, ROUND(SUM(amount),2) AS balance FROM b GROUP BY id) d
    ON c.id = d.id
WHERE c.balance <> d.balance))
```

Yields...

```
+----+----------+
| ID |  AMOUNT  |
+----+----------+
|123 |  -420.07 |
|123 |   420.07 |
|123 |  -420.07 |
+----+----------+
```

Comment: What is the PK (Primary Key) of Table B? That should be stored in Table A, then you see what is missing by joining ang filtering on .`Is Null`.

Comment: Are you asking if the PK in Table B represents the same transactions as the PK in Table A?

Comment: What is the PK in Table B (composite ID/Timestamp)?, That needs to be stored in Table A!

Comment: It is the composite ID.

Comment: What are the individual fields the PK is composite of? ID is not unique, so no PK!

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up more on [joins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198084.aspx) . There are 3 basic joins which can make life much simpler.

**INNER JOIN:** First, this is not asked, but the query you have provided for finding off balance items is too complicated. It can be simplified by an inner join. 
Inner join is a set operation which will basically get data from both tables (set) which match the condition.

```
select * from 
    (
        (select id, sum(amount) from a group by id) group_A
        INNER JOIN (select id, sum(amount) from b group by id) group_B
        ON group_A.id = group_B.id
        WHERE group_A.balance != group_B.balance
    )
```

**LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN:** Left outer join is an operation which will return all the data that is present in both sets and also the data that is in left set but not the right set. Right join is essential same operation on the right set. Important to notice that the extra records pulled here would be null for the side where they do not exist.

Since you want records which are present in table B but not in A, there are multiple ways of achieving this, one would be to get records present in both tables (inner join) and then get all the records in table B but not in the inner join done earlier. Using definition of group_A/group_B from the inner join example.

```
select id from b where id not in (
select id from group_A INNER JOIN group_B on group_A.id = group_B.id)
```

Or you can do a right outer join and then using the property of that fields fetched from table A would be coming as null, can filter out the required ID.

```
select group_B.id from group_A RIGHT OUTER JOIN group_B ON group_A.id = group_B.id
where group_A.id is null
```

**Please use the primary keys on the joins to get the correct results as mentioned by user @ComputerVersteher**

Comment: You recognized desired result is just one row? As your query will show all transactions with the id that is not complete and OP got that result himself (But your code if even better). Without the PK of table B stored as FK in A it will get difficult. Be aware that relying on balance is not equal can lead to missing results (e.g Missing Purchase and Refund of same value). You should count the number of transactions per id in both tables and compare them too.

Comment: I think I see what you both mean. In my specific case, table A and table B get updated from different tables. The primary keys given to Table B would be given to the records based on the order of creation. Since table A doesn't get updated from Table B, that PK column wouldn't be much helpful. It is my job to balance these tables based solely on the the ID column and amounts, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should add PK col.
I can't match data with table A and B, and can't seperate 2 rows at table B.

```
+----+----------+---------------------------+
| ID |  AMOUNT  |    RECEIVED TIMESTAMP     |
+----+----------+---------------------------+
|123 |  -420.07 | 2018-09-05-09.26.15.000000|<-
|123 |   420.07 | 2018-09-05-08.12.03.000000|
|123 |  -420.07 | 2018-09-05-08.40.00.000000|<-
|456 |    -5.00 | 2018-09-05-08.45.00.000000|
+----+----------+---------------------------+
```

I add new col(deal_no) and made it.
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3GfZoQwGhBLf7YWf2RucBF/4

```
select tmp_B.deal_no, tmp_B.id, tmp_B.amount, tmp_A.deal_no
  from tmp_B
       left outer join tmp_A
                    on tmp_A.deal_no = tmp_B.deal_no
 where tmp_A.deal_no is null
```